# How do I use UFW to block a device in Ubuntu hotspot?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw, hot-spot

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 20.04, which connected to the internet via ethernet.
I have setup a WiFi hotspot on this machine, so that I can share its internet connection.

Say, I have third device (a mobile phone), with IP A.B.C.D, which is connected to this hotspot.
How can I use UFW (or iptables) to block **any** communication from and to the third device (i.e., A.B.C.D)?

I tried the following:

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny to A.B.C.D from any
sudo ufw insert 1 deny from A.B.C.D to any
```

but the third device can still communicate with the outside without any issue

Comment: Is blocking an IP enough? Devices can be granted different IPs depending on the assignment rules of the DHCP provider. If the device does not rotate MAC addresses, you could add a rule to UFW to block all traffic from a MAC regardless the IP 

Comment: The IP is fixed (at least when I attempted the above). The MAC is fixed. I am sure that the device does not rotate them. Regardless, the problem persists. It is as if the UFW commands does not affect the wireless network interface. Is this possible?

Comment: The problem as I see it is that when you use your laptop as a hotspot, it acts as if it is a router and assigns an IP address A.B.C.D to the connected device (phone). However, when the device connects to the Internet, the request goes from the laptop's IP address. This is called Network Address Translation (NAT). As far as `ufw` is concerned it is monitoring the traffic going out and coming in from the Internet, and only sees your laptop connecting to the outside world.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can avoid this?

Comment: What would be the format of a UFW command that is targeted towards a specific interface?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in `ufw`. You will need to work directly on `iptable`. I don't know how.

Comment: You want the phone to still be able to access the hotspot(to the internet), but you dont want any other device to be able to talk to it???? Or you just dont want any connection AT ALL to the phone??? If it's the latter, then just put security on the hotspot and don't give the phone the password. You didnt really say what the second device is and how it comes into play.

Comment: The third device does not have to be a phone per say. It could be anything. 
I am writing a program, where if certain conditions are met, it should block the third device (which is already connected to the hotspot) from communicating with the outside. 
This program runs in the laptop.

Comment: `ufw` is the wrong tool for this, you need the advanced power of pure `iptables` behind you in order to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use iptables to block particular users from accessing the mobile hotspot such as

```
 sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i <wlan interface> -o <LAN interface> -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j REJECT
```

In the above example, the wlan interface amd the LAN interface could be "wlan0" and "eth1", respectively. Moreover, "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" denotes the MAC address of the user to be blocked. Note that the internal wifi network is connected to the outer wolrd only via the LAN interface.  To unblock the user again, use:

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i <wlan interface> -o <LAN interface> -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: UFW is a frontend that uses `iptables` under the hood.  If OP uses UFW and iptables together it might not function right, or at the very least the iptables rules will be overwritten if a ufw change is made.